# How to inherit c++ header file?

Tags: c++, inheritance, header-files

In java there is no header file. We import Class and use function. We can also extend them. In C++ there is header file. We include them and use function. Now my question, how to inherit them like java extends and is it possible?

Comment: Just include the header for the definition, and then extend the class. Still, java and C++ are completely deifferent beasts.

Comment: There is no relation between classes and header files in C++, except by convention.

Answer (score 3):

Every program has its own way of doing something. In c++ you can do like:

```
//filename foo1.h
class foo1
{
}
```

Now inn another file say foo2.h

```
//filename foo2.h

#include "foo1.h"
class foo2 : public foo1
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Java combines two things which C++ separates: the class definition and the definition of its members.

Java:

```
class Example {

    private String s;

    protected static int i = 1;

    public void f() {
        System.out.println("...");
    }

    public Example() {
        s = "test";
    }
}
```

C++ class definition:

```
class Example
{
private:
    std::string s;

protected:
    static int i;

public:
    void f();
    Example();
};
```

C++ definition of members:

```
int Example::i = 1;

void Example::f()
{
    std::cout << "...\n";
}

Example::Example() :
    s("test")
{
}
```

The separation into *.h and *.cpp files is purely **conventional**. It typically makes sense to put the class definition into the *.h file and the definition of the members into the *.cpp file. The reason why it makes sense is that some other code using the class **only needs the class definition**, not the definition of its members. That "other code" includes subclasses. By providing the class definition in a separate file, a user of the class can just `#include` the header and doesn't need to bother with the *.cpp file.

(Note that the *.cpp file, too, needs to `#include` its corresponding header file.)

If that looks complicated to you, view it from a different perspective. It allows you to modify the definition of the members without users of your class having to recompile their code. This is a big *advantage* of C++ compared to Java! The larger your project, the more important an advantage it becomes.

Answer (score -4):

The general way of doing this in c++ with inheritance/polymorphism is by stating the following:

`#include "myheaderfile.h"`

Comment: #include had nothing to do with inheritance or polymorphism :-/